# Help with Simulating a Time Series Process in R

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, statistics, time-series

I'm having difficulty expressing the following process in its most reduced form. Every time I try to simulate it with the arima.sim function, I end up with a non-stationary AR part that cannot be simulated.

The process is part of a school project where it says :

> Simulate under $R$, for $n = 500$, the process
>
> $(1 - B^{52})(1 - 2B + B^2)(1 - 2B)X_t = \varepsilon_t - \varepsilon_{t-1}, \quad t = 1, \ldots, n,$
>
> ensuring to express it in its most reduced form, under the assumption
> that the residuals are i.i.d. Gaussian $N(0,1)$.

Comment: Hi! Can you please explain the notation? Is $B$ a lag operator, or is it something else? What does $-> \epsilon_{t-1}$ mean?

Comment: Hi, $B$ is the lag/backshift operator. $-> \varepsilon_{t-1}$ was a blocknote typo, sorry.

Comment: Your process contains multiple unit roots, so you may need to simulate it manually (without use of  `arima.sim`).